# Power of a laser beam

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have the following function $$u(x,y,z)=\frac{Ak_0w_0^2}{2iz+k_0w_0^2}\exp\left(-k_0\frac{x^2+y^2}{2iz+k_0w_0^2}\right),$$ where $A,k_0,w_0$ are constants. I want to compute the following quantity $$P=\int\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|u(x,y,z)|^2dxdy,$$ showing that it does not depend on $z$. I dont really know how to deal with $|u(x,y,z)|$. I tried to separate $$\frac{1}{2iz+k_0w_0^2},$$ into real and imaginary part but i don't end up with something manageable. Any help will be very appreciated!

EDITED: Asuming $z>0$, from @K.dfaoite answer $$G(z)=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}|u(x,y;z)|^2\mathrm dx\mathrm dy \\ =\left|\frac{Ak_0{\omega_0}^2}{2\mathrm iz+k_0{\omega_0}^2}\right|^2\iint_{\mathbb R^2}\exp\left[-2 \mathfrak R\left(\frac{k_0}{2\mathrm iz+k_0{\omega_0}^2}\right)~(x^2+y^2)\right]\mathrm dx\mathrm dy.$$ Since $$\frac{1}{2iz+k_0w_0^2}=\frac{k_0w_0^2-2iz}{(k_0w_0^2)^2-4z^2}.$$ we have that $$-2 \mathfrak R\left(\frac{k_0}{2\mathrm iz+k_0{\omega_0}^2}\right)=-\frac{2k_0^2w_0^2}{k_0^2w_0^4-4z^2},$$ so $$\iint_{\mathbb R^2}\exp\left[-2 \mathfrak R\left(\frac{k_0}{2\mathrm iz+k_0{\omega_0}^2}\right)~(x^2+y^2)\right]\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\pi\frac{k_0^2w_0^4-4z^2}{2k_0^2w_0^2}.$$ On the other hand $$\left|\frac{Ak_0{\omega_0}^2}{2\mathrm iz+k_0{\omega_0}^2}\right|^2=A^2k_0^4w_0^4\left|\frac{1}{2iz+k_0w_0^2}\right|^2=\frac{A^2k_0^2w_0^4}{(k_0^2w_0^4-4z^2)^2}(k_0^2w_0^4+4z^2),$$using both thins we clearly see that the power $P$ does depend on $z$,$$P=\frac{\pi A^2w_0^2}{2}\frac{k_0^2w_0^4+4z^2}{k_0^2w_0^4-4z^2},$$ which is not the result that should be... I don't see any mistake. Any help will be very appreciated!!

Comment: I'm trying to think of a way to use polar coordinates, with a scaling to account for the extra multiplier in the exponent.

Comment: What quantities are complex? Looks like you could just rationalize the denominator to start. Ex: $1/(a+bi) = (a-bi)/(a^2+b^2)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because our domain of integration doesn't depend on $z$, I will simply define a complex constant
$$s=\frac{k_0}{2\mathrm iz+k_0{\omega_0}^2}$$
And set
$$B=\frac{Ak_0{\omega_0}^2}{2\mathrm iz+k_0{\omega_0}^2}$$
So that our function can be written as
$$u(x,y;z)=B\exp(-s(x^2+y^2))$$
Let's forget the constant $B$ and just consider the  function
$$v(x,y;s)=\exp(-s(x^2+y^2))$$
Since $x^2+y^2\in\mathbb R$, we can write
$$|v(x,y;s)|^2=|\mathrm e^{-s(x^2+y^2)}|=\big|\mathrm e^{-\mathfrak R(s)(x^2+y^2)}\cdot \mathrm e^{-\mathrm i~\mathfrak I(s)(x^2+y^2)}\big|^2$$
And since $|\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\theta}|=1$ for all $\theta\in\mathbb R$, this means
$$|v(x,y;s)|^2=\big|\mathrm e^{-\mathfrak R(s)(x^2+y^2)}\big|^2=\mathrm e^{-2\mathfrak R(s)~(x^2+y^2)}$$
With this in mind we let $2\mathfrak R(s)=t$ and define
$$w(x,y;t)=\mathrm e^{-t(x^2+y^2)}$$
Now all you need to do is calculate
$$F(t)=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}w(x,y;t)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$
This is easy if you know the Gaussian integral. Then, just trace back our substitutions
$$G(z)=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}|u(x,y;z)|^2\mathrm dx\mathrm dy \\ =\iint_{\mathbb R^2}|B|^2|v(x,y;s)|^2\mathrm dx\mathrm dy \\ =\iint_{\mathbb R^2}|B|^2w(x,y;t)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$

Subbing everything in, it should be
$$G(z)=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}|u(x,y;z)|^2\mathrm dx\mathrm dy \\ =\left|\frac{Ak_0{\omega_0}^2}{2\mathrm iz+k_0{\omega_0}^2}\right|^2\iint_{\mathbb R^2}\exp\left[-2 \mathfrak R\left(\frac{k_0}{2\mathrm iz+k_0{\omega_0}^2}\right)~(x^2+y^2)\right]\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$

---

**edit: complex number calculations**

Assuming $z$ is real, you can calculate
$$\left|\frac{Ak_0{\omega_0}^2}{2\mathrm iz+k_0{\omega_0}^2}\right|^2=\frac{A^2{k_0}^2{\omega_0}^4}{4z^2+{k_0}^2{\omega_0}^4}$$
And,
$$\mathfrak R\left(\frac{k_0}{2\mathrm iz+k_0{\omega_0}^2}\right)=\frac{{k_0}^2{\omega_0}^2}{4z^2+{k_0}^2{\omega_0}^4}$$
And so the factors of $4z^2+{k_0}^2{\omega_0}^2$ will cancel out.

Comment: +1, but shouldn't the last line be $\left|\frac{Ak_0{\omega_0}^2}{2\mathrm iz+k_0{\omega_0}^2}\right|^2$ i.e. should be the norm of $B^2$?

Comment: @Marco My mistake; corrected.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you read my edit? I don't know where i made a mistake but using this i don't get the desired result

Comment: @GonzalodeUlloa You must have made a mistake in your calculations of the squared norm and real part, because I am getting different results, which I have checked with a CAS.

Comment: I just computed $|k_0^2w_0^4-2iz|$ as $k_0^4w_0^8-4z^2$, my god what a mistake.... Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you made a first order approximation, for what ever reason, in your waist function:
$$ 
\frac{1}{1+\frac{2iz}{k_0 w_0^2}} 
$$
I suggest you make the full expansion
$$
\frac{1}{\cos(\frac{2z}{k_0 w_0^2}) + i\sin(\frac{2z}{k_0 w_0^2})}  
$$
and rationalize it. Your desired result will easily fall out.